# Thread safe parallel list computation using RcppParallel

Tags: r, rcpp, rcppparallel

I'm attempting to write code in C++ that loops over an `Rcpp::List` of `IntegerVector`s. The computation itself is complicated to explain, but for the sake of example let's suppose that I wanted to take the sum of sums of each `IntegerVector` (ignoring the fact that I could concatenate this list into one `IntegerVector`). This could be achieved by the following code:

```
int sumIntegerVector(const Rcpp::IntegerVector vec) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < vec.length(); i++) {
    sum += vec[i];
  }
  return sum;
}

int sumList(const Rcpp::List l){

  int sum = 0;
  for (int j = 0; j < l.length(); j++) {
    sum += sumIntegerVector(l[j]);
  }
  return sum;

}
```

Now, I would like to make this computation thread safe, so that I could parallelize over the loop in the `sumList` function (and not the `sumIntegerVector` function). Is there any thread safe way of doing this? I'm aware that Rcpp has a template `RVector` for thread safety. However, because I am looping over a list, it doesn't seem like the `RVector` template would be sufficient. Is there an `RList` template or something equivalent? Otherwise, could someone suggest a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems more complicated than the RcppParallel examples that take advantage of _contiguous_ memory making creation of `RVector` and `RMatrix` fairly "cheap".  With Lists you may have to copy content into non-R-owned memory first which may put a hurdle on performance you will have to amortise in your parallel code taking advantage of what you got via the upfront cost.